# Write to the textbox only if the condition is true in Matlab

Tags: matlab, callback, textbox

I struggle with printing text in my Matlab GUI.

I have code like this in my callback:

```
if Lia == ismember(handles.T(1:3),(1,1,1))
    set(handles.t1, 'String', 'good day');
end
```

The problem is, I don't know how to check if in my array indexes from 1 to 3 I got this numbers: 1,1,1. I was looking to the documentation but it appears it says nothing about that (or I simply cannot find the proper answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`all`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) and check to see if every element in the first three slots of your array match the values of 1 explicitly.  I don't know the shape of your array so I'm going to force it to be a column vector.  If the first three slots of the array was a row or column vector and if we assumed that the values of 1 are a column or row vector respectively then you're going to get a rather unpleasant surprise:

```
h = handles.T(1:3);
if all(h(:) == [1; 1; 1])
    set(handles.t1, 'String', 'good day');
end
```

Note that I could have simply done `all(h(:) == 1)` as a special case since we are performing a comparison of every element in an array with a single value.  However, I have a feeling that this may change for you, so I've decided to explicitly make a vector of 1s so you can change the contents of what you want to compare to at a later time.

Comment: I mean, if i want to check another 3 elements in another condition (same code, but different elements in array)

Comment: @Buszman Yes it can.  If you wanted to check three elements at a time until the end of the array and each three elements with a different vector it's possible, but it will require more code.